# How do I install Powershell's IISAdministration Module

Tags: iis, powershell, windows-server-2016

Windows Server 2016 comes with a shiny new module named IISAdministration.  But when I try to load the module I get the error that 'no valid module file was found'.  It is not on the powershell gallery and google does not find a download on the internet.

So where is that module hiding?  How to I get it installed on my Windows Server 2016?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

--Update--
This is now available as a stand-alone Powershell Module in the PS Gallery.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/IISAdministration/1.1.0.0

It turns out that the IISAdministration powershell module is a server feature.

With PowerShell you enable it with 
`Install-WindowsFeature web-scripting-tools`

Or from the Server Manager GUI, under Server Roles, you select: 
`Web Server (IIS) -> Management Tools -> IIS Management Scripts and Tools`

Comment: `web-mgmt-console` is not the feature that enables `IIS Management Scripts and Tools`. It is `web-scripting-tools`. i.e. `Install-WindowsFeature web-scripting-tools`. Followed by, `Import-Module WebAdministration`.

Comment: @Appleoddity  thanks for the comment.  I updated the Answer

Answer (score 4):

Here you find details to install **IISAdministration** in [different environments](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/IISAdministration/1.1.0.0)

On windows/windows server we can install module using

```
Install-Module -Name IISAdministration
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install that feature using a windows PowerShell console with elevated privileges (running it as administrator).

You can't install it from internet since it's within the IIS role of windows server, so you would need to install IIS 1st and then you can import it whenever you needed too.

So the step by step would be
    *     Server manager/Add Roles and Features/Next/Role-based or feature-based installation/SelectYourserver/next

[image: IIS Picture]

then next next next... and install.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot.  This is actually in the 'IIS Management Scripts and Tools' feature, not in the 'IIS Management Console'.